# How can I redirect to my verification page?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I added a registration section to my site. I added the code below (JavaScript) that redirects to the verify page if the information is entered correctly. When the information is entered correctly, the message "Success" appears and does not redirect to the verification page. The same applies to the login and verification page.

This is my PHP code:

```
if($otp){
      $receiver = $email;
      $subject = "From: $name <$name>";
      $body = "Name "." $name \n Email "." $email \n "." $otp";
      $sender = "From: xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";

      if(mail($receiver,$subject,$body,$sender)){
      echo "Success.";
      }
}
```

And this is my JavaScript code:

```
submitbtn.onclick = () =>{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","./signup.php" ,true);
    xhr.onload = () => {
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
            if(xhr.status == 200){
                let data = xhr.response;
                if(data == "success"){
                    location.href = "./verify.php"
                }
                else{
                    errortxt.textContent = data;
                    errortxt.style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

[image: Website after unsucessful redirect]

Comment: Presumably the php code perhaps outputs something extra like a space character or something which makes it not match

Comment: try `location.pathname = 'verify.php'`

Comment: Notice that you echo this in your PHP `Success.` but in your Javascript you do this `if(data == "success")`.  That is, the sentinel must match.

Comment: Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: I did what you said and the error persists. When I submit the form, the text on the screen appears and does not send it to the verify page. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/946Z5.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code, you want "success" to be the indicator that the JavaScript will detect to know when to do the redirection. As such since your condition is equality `==` with no other transformations, what your PHP outputs and what your JavaScript checks for needs to be the same.

```
if($otp){
      $receiver = $email;
      $subject = "From: $name <$name>";
      $body = "Name "." $name \n Email "." $email \n "." $otp";
      $sender = "From: xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";

      if(mail($receiver,$subject,$body,$sender)){
      echo "Success.";  // <--- This line
      }
}
```

Change the echo line to:

```
echo "success";
```

So that it matches what the JavaScript checks for.

It's still possible even with this fix that you won't get a match due to as ADyson mentions of errant white space. So it would be a good idea in this and future debugging to console.log the response of the ajax call.

```
...
let data = xhr.response;
console.log(data);
...
```

As a start.

Comment: I did what you said but I still get the same error. and when I submit the form, the message "success" appears on the screen.

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/946Z5.png) image when I run the code

Comment: Then you must have some other logic in your code that you don't excerpt in your question. Perhaps include more of your source code, such as the code for your html(?) button and the code for the form you show in your image.

Comment: I threw all the codes related to the problem

Comment: As mentioned in my answer and (by ADyson in comments), you *also* have to ensure that your PHP side is not putting in extra characters in the response, accidently or incidently. For example, if there is any white space or newline before your starting `<?php` then that will get outputted out too, messing up the match.

Comment: I mentioned the console.log idea in my answer as a "start". You can extend on it to make sure that no whitespace is being returned as well. For example, `console.log(data.length)` which you would want to be 7 chars. Another example, `console.log("[" + data + "]")` which should be `[success]` with no gaps between the brackets.

Comment: I have checked my codes many times and there is no error. What I write is saved in the database. The only problem is that it does not redirect to another page after saving the form. I think this is related to the code I wrote in javascript. php codes `echo "success";` I added it because I don't know whether to add an addition to the code.

Comment: There is an error. It's called a *logical error*. Your job is to use the tools available to you to track it down. Open the developer console in your browser and start putting console.log() in your JavaScript to aide in debugging. This is standard practice.